# multiple conditions in an if statement in javascript

Tags: javascript

I know there has been a question like this, but mine is a little different, and it already works, but I don't know how to simplify it.

`` if (location.pathname === `/` || location.pathname ===`/kurikulum/` || location.pathname === `/pengembangan-diri/` || location.pathname === `/statistik/` || location.pathname === `/teknologi/` || location.pathname === `/ekonomi/` || location.pathname === `/desain/` || location.pathname === `/corona/`) ``

as you can see it is not beautiful, I wonder can we make it without repeating  `location.pathname`?

this is on gatsby, but it is a javascript question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Array.includes` to check if the current pathname exists in a given array.

```js
let pathArr = ['/', '/kurikulum/', '/pengembangan-diri/', '/statistik/', '/teknologi/', '/ekonomi/', '/desain/', '/corona/'];
let testPath = '/desain/';

if (pathArr.includes(testPath)) {
   document.write('path found!');
};
```

Learn more about `Array.includes` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Comment: what if we want to make it the other way around ?  like ```/path/``` that is now in the array?

Comment: @MuhZulzidan what do you intend to do here? Can't understand.

Answer (score 3):

Use `includes()`, it will return true or false if the value is in the array.

```js
const pathnames = [
  '/',
  '/kurikulum/',
  '/pengembangan-diri/',
  '/statistik/',
  '/teknologi/',
  '/ekonomi/',
  '/desain/',
  '/corona/'
]

if (pathnames.includes(location.pathname)) {
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can put all of your paths into a path array then run an indexOf() function to see if something fits

```js
const paths = ['/', '/path', '/path1']
const thePath = '/',

if (paths.indexOf(thepath) >= 0) {
  console.log('the path exists')
} else {
console.log('the path doesnt exist')
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way is that you can use array.filter or array.some.

```
const words = ['spray', 'limit', 'elite', 'exuberant', 'destruction', 'present'];
const searchFunc = (searchItem) => words.filter(word => word === searchItem).length > 0;
if(searchFunc('limit')){
  console.log("Item is found");
}

// expected output: "Item is found"
```

Answer (score -2):

You can simplify by define an JavaScript array of objects like below:

```
{
  path: '/some-path-to-compare`,
}
```

Then instead of compare by lot of lines, use loop then compare with the `path` field.